# Pyparsing, Python 3 and the Unicode byte order mark

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pyparsing, python-unicode

I have a text file which is UTF-8 encoded with the byte order mark present - that is, the first few bytes are `EF BB BF 0D 0A 4D...` (it's a Visual Studio solution file produced by VS 2013).

I'm trying to parse this with PyParsing, using the `parseFile()` method and Python 3.  In Python 2, I could do this:

```
import pyparsing as pp
bom = pp.Optional(unicode(unichr(0xfeff)).encode('utf-8')).suppress()
```

to get an optional byte order mark.  But in Python 3, the `unicode` and `unichr` functions have gone away because all strings are Unicode.  So I tried this:

```
bom = pp.Optional(chr(0xfeff)).suppress()
```

and this:

```
bom = pp.Optional('\ufeff').suppress()
```

but neither matches the start of the file.  I've googled for a while but can't seem to turn up anything relevant.

How can I match (or just ignore!) the Unicode byte order mark?

Comment: Aren't visual studio solution files XML?

Comment: Um, not the ones I'm looking at.  The project files definitely are, but the solution files are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem here is that the default encoding used when reading a file using the `parseFile()` method is ASCII, so the UTF-8-encoded byte order mark doesn't end up as `U+FEFF`, it ends up as ASCII `EF BB BF`.  To work around this, you can open the file explicitly and specify the encoding.  Instead of this:

```
p.parseFile('filename.sln')
```

do this:

```
p.parseFile(open('filename.sln', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Then the byte order mark can be skipped with the following parser:

```
bom = pp.Optional(chr(0xfeff)).suppress()
```

Comment: Or open the file, read the contents using `.read()`, then call `parseString` - `parseFile` is just a minimal convenience wrapper around `parseString`.

Answer (score 4):

Open the file using `utf_8_sig` encoding type:

```
p.parseFile(open('filename.sln', encoding='utf_8_sig'))
```

The BOM will be suppressed if it's present.

From the codecs module:

> On encoding a UTF-8 encoded BOM will be prepended to the UTF-8 encoded bytes. For the stateful encoder this is only done once (on the first write to the byte stream). For decoding an optional UTF-8 encoded BOM at the start of the data will be skipped.